# Map object properties to list with automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have an object with a lot of properties. 
Now I want to map some of this properties to collection using Automapper.
Source looks like:

```
class MySource
{
   public string Property1 {get; set;}
   public string Property1Link {get; set;}
   public string Property2 {get; set;}
   public string Property2Link {get; set;} 
}
```

And as Destination I want to get List or IEnumarable of such objects:

```
class MyDestinationObj
{
  public string Title{get; set;}
  public string Value{get; set;}
  public string Link{get; set;}
}
```

So, for example, if MySource object is set as:

```
MySource source=new MySource
{
  Property1="val1",
  Property1Link="google.com",
  Property2="val2",
  Property2Link="yahoo.com"
};
```

As result I want to see list of two objects:

```
MyDestinationObj obj1=new MyDestinationObj
{
  Title="Property1",
  Value="val1",
  Link="google.com"
}
MyDestinationObj obj2=new MyDestinationObj
{
  Title="Property2",
  Value="val2",
  Link="yahoo.com"
}
```

I can't figure out how I can do that.
Is it possible with Automapper?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html